# Oracle Character Collection

Tags: oracle

I have a query that does the union of 3 tables when doing it in a database configured with a collection of characters AL32UTF8 it takes me a while to execute 43sg, in another database configured with a collection of characters WE8MSWIN1252 it takes 4sg What is the role What does the character collection play when querying? My question is the following:

```
select name from empleados where username='Ari' and rol in ('limpiador', 'recursos humanos', 'docente', 'alumno') union select name from grupo1 inner join grupo2 on grupo1.groupname=grupo2.groupname where username='abs' and rol in ('alumno', 'docente', 'recursos humanos', 'limpia pisos', 'chofer')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the abbreviation "sg".  Is that "seconds"?  Or some other unit?  Is the query plan the same in both databases?  I'd rather strongly suspect that the issue is that there is something different in the inputs to the query optimizer that is causing the systems to produce different query plans rather than a difference caused by the database character set.  Is there a reason you believe the character set is the source of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the only difference is the character set? For example: are both databases running on the same computer? If not, you should suspect differences in hardware (speed of reading data from disk, for example) before you ever look at character sets.

Comment: They are seconds, the execution is carried out on the same computer, and it is the only variant that the instances have, one with AL32UTF8 and the other with WE8MSWIN1252, check the execution plans and they are very different in both cases for AL32UTF8 it gives me a cost of 138 and for WE8MSWIN1252 it is only 7, it is also something that causes me a lot of noise

Comment: Can you reduce the query to something simple enough to show on Stackoverflow, which is still faster on WE8MSWIN1252 than on AL32UTF8? For instance union of only 2 tables, less column etc? If you edit your question and post the create table statements, and may be some INSERT statements, we can try to reproduce your measurement and hopefully answer your question...

Comment: I have already placed it

Answer (score 2):

Like Justin or mathguy, I don't believe the character set will cause a ten time slower execution, at least I would be very surprised.

To your question: Oracle Corp was founded in [1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation), 14 years before the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Unicode_Consortium).

Back then, you needed to chose which character a byte value represents, for instance `0x40 = A`, `0x41 = B` etc. The set of those characters is called a "character set", they got a name and where standardized. Oracle put a lot of effort into this, for instance, when the client (your application) and the server (the database) use a different character set, Oracle tries to do some mapping to convert the byte values, so that an 'A' on one side is also an 'A' on the other side, even when the byte values are different.

Most of the old systems use only on byte per character, which makes it fast and easy to work with. You'll want to know the 14th character? Just go to the start and jump 14 bytes, and you're there.

Other character sets, like AL32UTF8 use one byte for the most common Latin characters, but up to four bytes for other characters. Jumping to the fourteenths character is not so easy any more, you need to go to the start and work your way character by character until you're there.

This is slower, but certainly not ten times slower.

It can also use more storage and memory, but again, not ten times. CLOBs are stored as 16 byte values in a varying width character set like AL32UTF8, so they are 2x the size compared to WE8MSWIN1252, though.

Comment: As I mention to Justin and Mathguy, the execution is carried out on the same computer, and it is the only variant that the instances have, because they are exactly the same 3 tables that I make the query, one with AL32UTF8 and the other with WE8MSWIN1252, check the execution plans and they are very different in both cases for AL32UTF8 it gives me a cost of 138 and for WE8MSWIN1252 it is only 7, it is also something that causes me a lot of noise, that's why my doubt about what role the collection plays of characters?